# Center of bounding box Yolo

Tags: python, yolo, bounding-box

I tried palm counting with Yolov7. The detection result is below. I would now like to get the coordinates of the center of the bounding box and use that to determine the gps position of each palm tree. I tried to use the coordinates of the upper left corner as a reference but the result obtained is not good the points do not end up in the center of the box when I draw them simultaneously. Can you help me ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGEix.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to get the coordinates of the center of the bounding box and draw it on the image instead of the bounding box.